# jq loop over objects and use shell command output to add a field

Tags: json, bash, gitlab, jq

I'm trying to iterate over a JSON and add a field to each object in the JSON.
I'm doing this in a Gitlab pipeline stage but I don't think is important.

The JSON is this:

```
{
 "service10": {
     "path_to_file" : "service10.txt"
     },
"service192": {
     "path_to_file" : "service192.txt"
     }
}
```

What I'm doing is using the `path_to_file` to check in a Gitlab repo if that file exists and I need to save the http response, the code now looks as follows:

```
check_files_existence:
  stage: update-external-repo
  script:
    - apt-get update --fix-missing
    - apt-get install jq -y
    - HTTP_RESPONSE_CODES=()

    # Check for file
    - |-
      for FILE_TO_CHECK in $(jq -r '.[].path_to_file ' $JSON_TO_READ); do
        
        last_status_code=($(curl [omitted]))
        
        HTTP_RESPONSE_CODES+=($last_status_code)      
        
       done

   # Write array of responses into artifact
    - echo "${HTTP_RESPONSE_CODES[@]}" >> ./http_response_code.txt

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./http_response_code.txt
    expire_in: 10 min
```

This generates a .txt file with the http responses separated by a whitespace.

What I want to do is add a field to each service while I loop over them with the http_response, so the JSON will be like:

```
{
 "service10": {
     "path_to_file" : "service10.txt",
     "http_response": 200
     },
"service192": {
     "path_to_file" : "service192.txt",
     "http_response": 404
     }
}
```

And then I'm going to export this an artifact to use it in another stage in my Gitlab Pipeline.

Using the above for loop I can get the file path but then it looks like I cannot update the JSON, if I use something like

```
for OBJECT in $(jq -r '.[] ' $JSON_TO_READ)
```

I cannot read the file path because using

```
jq '.path_to_file $OBJECT'
```

returns an error.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. It's hard to give a verifiably correct answer without at least a small sample of valid illustrative JSON.

Comment: `jq '.path_to_file $OBJECT' ` looks wrong, shouldn't that be `jq '.path_to_file' "$OBJECT"`

Comment: @peak Sorry, but there is a Json in the question with omitted fields as those are not important. The output json is the same with the extra field for all the objects.

Comment: You have offered a sketch of the JSON, which is fine, but an actual snippet of illustrative, valid JSON, would be helpful.  Otherwise, it's hard to know whether the problem you have is due to invalid JSON, or not.  Incidentally, you can use jsonlint.com to verify validity.

Comment: @peak I can use a JSON with a single field per object, that is also fine. I validated the JSON via jsonlint.com. 
Let's say we have this JSON, I loop over the objects, check with a curl if that file exists and add another field to each object. 

INPUT:

{
 "service10": {
  "file_to_check": "file_to_check1.txt"
 },
 "service192": {
  "file_to_check": "file_to_check1.txt"
 }
}

OUTPUT:

{
 "service10": {
  "file_to_check": "file_to_check1.txt",
                 "hr": 404
 },
 "service192": {
  "file_to_check": "file_to_check1.txt",
                 "hr": 200
 }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add valid JSON (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus Done, sorry! I thought it was not important to have an exact copy of my JSON!

Comment: It doesn't need to be the _exact_ JSON, but it does need to be JSON that causes _the exact same problem_, such that something that works for your example will also solve your real problem.

Comment: BTW, [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Better practice in the bash world is `while IFS= read -r json_object; do ...; done < <(jq -c ...)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the heads up, I'm kinda new to the bash world and I'm still learning :)

Comment: (BTW, it looks like you JSON is still needing some edits? It's missing quotes right now; `service10:` needs to be `"service10":`, unless your real data format is YAML and not JSON at all; if that's the case it would call for a different answer, since jq won't work with YAML (except the subset of YAML that's also JSON) without something doing conversion on the way in)

Comment: @charlesDuffy fixed the JSON, hopefully for good this time, sorry again but I edited that object like four times and it created a bit of caos! :) Plus, I said it works in the code that I'm now using, I'm just missing how to add the field. I guess I need to change the loop but I can't manage to find the right way.

Comment: Right, but we can't test our code against your data unless your data actually works; and if we guess at how to fix it we might guess wrong. (`"path_to_file"` is quoted now, but `service10` and `service192` still aren't).

Comment: I recommend you familiarize yourself further with the syntax of JSON before continuing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fixed, sorry again!

Comment: @Cyrus I'm familiar with the Json format, I was just changing the json here and in my code multiple times so I got kinda messed, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably calls for two separate copies of jq. Assuming your input file were changed to be valid JSON:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value.path_to_file] | @tsv' <"$JSON_TO_READ" \
| while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do
    # comment this next line in your real system
    (( ++http_status )) # stand-in so this can be tested without calling curl
    # uncomment this next line and replace the url in your real system
    #http_status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "http://example.com/$key") || continue
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$key" "$http_status"
  done \
| jq -Rn --slurpfile input_file "$JSON_TO_READ" '
    reduce inputs as $inline
      ($input_file[0];
       (($inline | split("\t")) as $pieces |
        .[$pieces[0]].http_response = ($pieces[1])))'
```

Breaking down the shell pipeline:

- First, we have a copy of jq that emits a tab-separated stream with your key and value. An entry here would look like:

  ```
  service10<TAB>service10.txt
  ```
- Next, we have a shell pipeline (running a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop) that reads these two variables, and runs curl (or in the example above, just adds an incrementing number as the status code) to determine the HTTP status code:

  ```
  service10<TAB>200
  ```
- Finally, we have another copy of jq that accepts your input file via `--slurpfile`, and reads the stream of tab-separated service keys and HTTP status codes from stdin, using a reducer to incrementally update the status file as new values come in. (Because `--slurpfile` contains a *list* of JSON documents found in the file, not just a single document, we're referring to `$input_file[0]` to refer to the first -- and only -- document in the file).

Comment: It works, I just had to output to a different file to then save it in the gitlab artifacts. Thank you for the answer and for guiding a bit in how to write a correct question on StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn't too big and you don't mind reading the same input file multiple times, then here is another solution that should work:

1. Count [the number of key-value-pairs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#length) in the object
2. Extract single entry by index from object
3. Get `path_to_file` value from entry
4. Call curl
5. Add `http_response` to entry
6. Use `jq -s` ([`--slurp`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq)) to reconstruct the object from its entries

```
input='input.json'
length="$(jq 'length' "$input")"
for i in $(seq "$length"); do
  entry="$(jq --argjson idx "$i" 'to_entries[$idx-1]' "$input")"
  path="$(printf '%s' "$entry" | jq -r '.value.path_to_file')"
  last_status_code="$(curl ... "$path")"
  printf '%s' "$entry" | jq --argjson status "$last_status_code" '.value.http_response = $status'
done | jq -s 'from_entries'
```

Comment: It works, I just had to use " jq -r  '.value.path_to_file' " to remove quotes from the path and " jq -s 'from_entries' > output.json " so I could save the file in Gitlab artifacts. 
Thank you! I have accept Charles Duffy answer but this is equally correct for what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Yes, correct, you need the `-r`/`--raw` option to get the string value without quotes, I missed that.

Comment: Running a lot more separate copies of jq here, but I suppose that's part of the reason for the "if your input isn't too big" disclaimer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, exactly why this answer starts with "If your file isn't too big and you don't mind reading the same input file multiple times". But it will handle services, paths or anything else regardless of embedded space or tab characters and newlines :)

Comment: Fair point; I suppose I should update my answer to switch to NUL-delimited fields.